# Scikit-Learn Decision Tree: Probability of prediction being a or b?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

I have a basic decision tree classifier with Scikit-Learn:

```
#Used to determine men from women based on height and shoe size

from sklearn import tree

#height and shoe size
X = [[65,9],[67,7],[70,11],[62,6],[60,7],[72,13],[66,10],[67,7.5]]

Y=["male","female","male","female","female","male","male","female"]

#creating a decision tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

#fitting the data to the tree
clf.fit(X, Y)

#predicting the gender based on a prediction
prediction = clf.predict([68,9])

#print the predicted gender
print(prediction)
```

When I run the program, it always outputs either "male" or "female", but how would I be able to see the probability of the prediction being male or female? For example, the prediction above returns "male", but how would I get it to print the probability of the prediction being male?

Thanks!

Comment: As answers have noted, you can use `predict_proba`, but beware the probabilities aren't very good: https://rpmcruz.github.io/machine%20learning/2018/02/09/probabilities-trees.html

Comment: "aren't very good" is an understatement.  Because you're using a decision tree, every sample is in the "male" branch or the "female" branch.  So the probability will always be 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can do something like the following:**

```
from sklearn import tree

#load data
X = [[65,9],[67,7],[70,11],[62,6],[60,7],[72,13],[66,10],[67,7.5]]
Y=["male","female","male","female","female","male","male","female"]

#build model
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

#fit
clf.fit(X, Y)

#predict
prediction = clf.predict([[68,9],[66,9]])

#probabilities
probs = clf.predict_proba([[68,9],[66,9]])

#print the predicted gender
print(prediction)
print(probs)
```

**Theory**

The result of `clf.predict_proba(X)` is: The predicted class probability which is the fraction of samples of the same class in a leaf.

**Interpretation of the results:**

The first `print` returns `['male' 'male']` so the data `[[68,9],[66,9]]` are predicted as `males`.

The second `print` returns:

`[[ 0.  1.]
  [ 0.  1.]]`

**This means that the data were predicted as males and this is reported by the ones in the second column.**

*To see the order of the classes use: `clf.classes_`*

This returns: `['female', 'male']`

Comment: Thank you for this! I decided to use a SVM instead of a decision tree for this problem, since it has a probability parameter. But this is a great answer!

Comment: I don't think you've provided a probability in the sense that OP was looking for. This just returns a similarly binary answer. I'm assuming OP is looking to provide some confidence, as in a logistic regression, so that most values will be between 0 and 1 but not equal to 0 or 1. I'm not even sure that's possible.

Comment: I believe that this is exactly what the OP asked for. He has also accepted my answer.

Comment: It just happens that the tree predicts 0% and 100% probabilities in this case. Other data will produce different probabilities.

If anyone happens to know whether something similar can be done for `DecisionTreeRegressor`s, I asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586860/equivalent-of-predict-proba-for-decisiontreeregressor.

Answer (score 1):

the answer in my top is correct,
you are getting binary output because your tree is complete and not truncate in order to make your tree weaker, you can use max_depth to a lower depth so probability won't be like [0. 1.] 
it will look like [0.25 0.85]
another problem here is that the dataset is very small and easy to solve so better to use a more complex dataset
some link that might make this more clear for you mate
https://rpmcruz.github.io/machine%20learning/2018/02/09/probabilities-trees.html
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.predict_proba

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to read the [sklearn documentation for DecisionTreeClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.predict_proba) and see:

```
predict_proba(X[, check_input])
```

Comment: I looked at the documentation a little. I tried to call
print(clf.predict_proba(X)) and I got this result:

[[ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]]

What does this mean?

Comment: You provided the data X, Y and you've asked the algorithm to predict X. That's why the probabilities are showing up as [0. 1.]

Comment: Just to clarify further, enter predict_proba(`what you are trying to predict`), not X. Does this make sense?

Comment: Oh, okay. So I would do predict_proba([68,9])?

Comment: Read the docs is never a helpful comment