# Equivalent of predict_proba for DecisionTreeRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, prediction, decision-tree

scikit-learn's `DecisionTreeClassifier` supports predicting probabilities of each class via the `predict_proba()` function. This is absent from `DecisionTreeRegressor`:

> AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeRegressor' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'

My understanding is that the underlying mechanics are pretty similar between decision tree classifiers and regressors, with the main difference being that predictions from the regressors are calculated as means of potential leafs. So I'd expect it to be possible to extract the probabilities of each value.

Is there another way to simulate this, e.g. by processing the [tree structure](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py)? The [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/55bf5d9/sklearn/tree/tree.py#L804) for `DecisionTreeClassifier`'s `predict_proba` wasn't directly transferable.

Comment: BTW I understand this [isn't likely to produce great results](https://rpmcruz.github.io/machine%20learning/2018/02/09/probabilities-trees.html). I'm looking to quantify the difference between random forests and trees for producing prediction intervals.

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/55bf5d9/sklearn/tree/tree.py#L804

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function adapts code from [hellpanderr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53592809/1840471) to provide probabilities of each outcome:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
import pandas as pd

def decision_tree_regressor_predict_proba(X_train, y_train, X_test, **kwargs):
    """Trains DecisionTreeRegressor model and predicts probabilities of each y.

    Args:
        X_train: Training features.
        y_train: Training labels.
        X_test: New data to predict on.
        **kwargs: Other arguments passed to DecisionTreeRegressor.

    Returns:
        DataFrame with columns for record_id (row of X_test), y 
        (predicted value), and prob (of that y value).
        The sum of prob equals 1 for each record_id.
    """
    # Train model.
    m = DecisionTreeRegressor(**kwargs).fit(X_train, y_train)
    # Get y values corresponding to each node.
    node_ys = pd.DataFrame({'node_id': m.apply(X_train), 'y': y_train})
    # Calculate probability as 1 / number of y values per node.
    node_ys['prob'] = 1 / node_ys.groupby(node_ys.node_id).transform('count')
    # Aggregate per node-y, in case of multiple training records with the same y.
    node_ys_dedup = node_ys.groupby(['node_id', 'y']).prob.sum().to_frame()\
        .reset_index()
    # Extract predicted leaf node for each new observation.
    leaf = pd.DataFrame(m.decision_path(X_test).toarray()).apply(
        lambda x:x.to_numpy().nonzero()[0].max(), axis=1).to_frame(
            name='node_id')
    leaf['record_id'] = leaf.index
    # Merge with y values and drop node_id.
    return leaf.merge(node_ys_dedup, on='node_id').drop(
        'node_id', axis=1).sort_values(['record_id', 'y'])
```

Example (see [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1O475-dUdJNtwg8osS8FfpVH_QeMRwf9g?usp=sharing)):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, y = load_boston(True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
# Works better with min_samples_leaf > 1.
res = decision_tree_regressor_predict_proba(X_train, y_train, X_test,
                                            random_state=0, min_samples_leaf=5)
res[res.record_id == 2]
#      record_id       y        prob
#   25         2    20.6    0.166667
#   26         2    22.3    0.166667
#   27         2    22.7    0.166667
#   28         2    23.8    0.333333
#   29         2    25.0    0.166667
```

Comment: `nonzero()` has been deprecated. The fix is to change to `to_numpy().nonzero()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get that data out of tree structure:

```
import sklearn
import numpy as np
import graphviz
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor, DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

# Generate a simple dataset
X, y = make_regression(n_features=2, n_informative=2, random_state=0)
clf = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0, max_depth=2)
clf.fit(X, y)
# Visualize the tree
graphviz.Source(sklearn.tree.export_graphviz(clf)).view()
```

[image]

```
>>> clf.predict(X[:5])

0     184.005667
1      53.017289
2     184.005667
3     -20.603498
4     -97.414461
```

If you call `clf.apply(X)` you will get a node id to which instance belongs to:

```
array([6, 5, 6, 3, 2, 5, 5, 3, 6, ... 5, 5, 6, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Merging it together with target variable:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([y, clf.apply(X)]), index=['y','node_id']).T
    y           node_id
0   190.370562  6.0
1   13.339570   5.0
2   141.772669  6.0
3   -3.069627   3.0
4   -26.062465  2.0
5   54.922541   5.0
6   25.952881   5.0
       ...
```

Now if you do a groupby on `node_id` followed by mean you will get the same values as `clf.predict(X)`

```
>>> df.groupby('node_id').mean()
                 y
node_id     
2.0     -97.414461
3.0     -20.603498
5.0     53.017289
6.0     184.005667
```

Which are the `value`s of leafs in our tree:

```
>>> clf.tree_.value[6]
array([[184.00566679]])
```

To get node ids for a new data set you need to call

`clf.decision_path(X[:5]).toarray()`

which shows you an array like this

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

where you need to get the last non-zero element (i.e. a leaf)

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(clf.decision_path(X[:5]).toarray()).apply(lambda x:x.nonzero()[0].max(), axis=1)
0    6
1    5
2    6
3    3
4    2
dtype: int64
```

So if instead of predicting mean you wanted to predict median you would do

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(clf.decision_path(X[:5]).toarray()).apply(lambda x: x.nonzero()[0].max(
    ), axis=1).to_frame(name='node_id').join(df.groupby('node_id').median(), on='node_id')['y']
0    181.381106
1     54.053170
2    181.381106
3    -28.591188
4    -93.891889
```

Comment: Thanks, this code was really helpful. I adapted it to get the probability of each value in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53601104/1840471.