# Input values return prediction with percentage

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, artificial-intelligence

Hi I have write machine learning use decision tree model. I create webapp that user can input and web will call to model by flask api and then show result on webapp but my result have only Yes/No. It possible if the result can show percentage how much this input will yes/no, Example  Yes 76%

Comment: Hi, perhaps use confidence intervals? https://medium.com/hal24k-techblog/how-to-generate-neural-network-confidence-intervals-with-keras-e4c0b78ebbdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use predict_proba() as it returns the class probabilities of the input samples X.

```
probs = clf.predict_proba(X)
# probs will output the probability of the prediction on each class.
```

You can read more about it in the documentation and in this other post with a similar question.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html

[Scikit-Learn Decision Tree: Probability of prediction being a or b?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251594/scikit-learn-decision-tree-probability-of-prediction-being-a-or-b)

Comment: Can  I ask more?   I want to know how to show result with cause, Example  when user input data and then model show result  "yes"  because ..........

Comment: Do you mean why the model made that prediction?

Comment: yes ex. this man fat because he He weighs 150 Kg. but i want to show that on my web to explain