# About scikit-learn: invalid syntax

Tags: scikit-learn

I try the code from [Scikit-Learn Decision Tree: Probability of prediction being a or b?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251594/scikit-learn-decision-tree-probability-of-prediction-being-a-or-b)

but, it gave syntax error, this is the code:

```
from scikit-learn import tree
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251594/scikit-learn-decision-tree-probability-of-prediction-being-a-or-b

#load data
X = [[65,9],[67,7],[70,11],[62,6],[60,7],[72,13],[66,10],[67,7.5]]
Y=["male","female","male","female","female","male","male","female"]

#build model
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

#fit
clf.fit(X, Y)

#predict
prediction = clf.predict([[68,9],[66,9]])

#probabilities
probs = clf.predict_proba([[68,9],[66,9]])

#print the predicted gender
print(prediction)
print(probs)
```

what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to import scikit-learn using `from sklearn import tree`.
It's the only error.